# Pouch DB sync rejected with 404 due to forward slash in document id

Tags: pouchdb

I have a PouchDB instance which syncs with SyncGateway Server. Some document ids contain "/" which is being urlencoded as "%2F" by pouchDB when doing a sync. These sync GET requests are receiving 404 errors as the server rejects "%2F" in the url. If I double urlencode this (by changing the encodeDocId(id) function in pouchdb.js then things work fine.

My queries:

1. Am I doing the right thing in going for one more encodeURIComponent(...)? What can be the issues with it, if any?
2. Can this is made configurable if it is not universally acceptable? Have a parameters to turn this on/off.
3. If this is not the right solution, then please suggest an alternative.

Comment: Is there a proxy between your client and server?

Comment: The best solution, if feasible, is not to use document IDs that need to be escaped. I realize that's not always possible.

Comment: there is a proxy but that cannot be removed. Cant change much on server side and setup.

Comment: My guess is that your proxy is not handling the escaping properly. The only "correct" solution is probably to change the proxy configuration, or to rename your documents not to use `/` characters in their IDs.